# Call reusable Github workflow from a feature branch is not working

Tags: github, reference, workflow, action

I'm currently working on a reusable workflow. I created a new feature branch to make changes and I'm trying to call it by triggering a workflow from another repository.

The call:

```
uses: {owner}/{repo}/.github/workflows/{workflow_file}.yml@{feature_branch}
```

It works perfectly if the ref is "master" or "develop", but when I try to reference the feature branch the executions fails with:

```
error parsing called workflow
".github/workflows/update_develop.yml"
-> "{owner}/{repo}/.github/workflows/{workflow_file}.yml@{feature_branch}" (source branch with sha:c9d3bbc17c1fdf6e855f2c28e8b6f4027e168fc6)
: the `uses' attribute must be a path, a Docker image, or owner/repo@ref
```

The repository containing the calable workflow has no caller restriction settings.

Again, referencing "master" or "develop" still works.

The reference actually exists. If I try to reference an inexistent branch it fails differently:

```
error parsing called workflow
".github/workflows/update_develop.yml"
-> "{owner}/{repo}/.github/workflows/{workflow_file}.yml@{inexistent_branch}"
: failed to fetch workflow: reference to workflow should be either a valid branch, tag, or commit
```

What could I be missing?

Thanks for the help in advance!

I tried to change the reference of the called workflow from "master" to a feature_branch and expected the workflow to run successfully with the changes I made in the feature_branch workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The error message was misleading**. The parse error was not in the workflow itself. There was a syntax error in a a composite action yaml file that is used by the reusable workflow. I activated the yaml language server on LunarVim and it pointed to the error. It was a misplaced ":" in the inputs section.  Fixing it get rid of the problem.

Comment: For any poor soul reaching here make sure that any external actions in `uses` ends with `@` and a tag/version. In my case I forgot to add `@v1` in one of the actions and this misleading error drove me crazy.